# Post a comment on a page/link true FB.api

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments

Is there a method for posting comments on pages with Facebooks js api? FB.api().
You can post on a persons wall with

```
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { caption: message, name: "the tile",  description: "a neat message", link : "http://www.stackoverflow.com" }, function(response) {});
```

But is there an equivalent of posting a comment to a page? Without the social-plugin "comments box". Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

All of the graph api is built on urls, all of the different SDKs (including the js one) just wrap up the http requests for you.

As the [documentation for page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) states:

> **feed**
>
> This connection corresponds to the Page's Wall. You can create a link,
>   post or status message by issuing an HTTP POST request to the
>   PAGE_ID/feed connection. To see more details please see links, posts,
>   and status messages documentation.
>
> To impersonate the Page when posting to the wall (i.e. post as the
>   Page, and not the current user), you must use a Page access_token with
>   the manage_pages and publish_stream permissions, as described under
>   [Page Access Tokens](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#page_access_tokens) above.

To do that from the javascript sdk then is something like this:

```
FB.api('/PAGE_ID/feed', 'post', { caption: message, name: "the tile",  description: "a neat message", link : "http://www.stackoverflow.com" }, function(response) {});
```

Comment: This seems correct, but it tells me "(#200) This API call requires a valid app_id". I tried adding `app_id: 'MY_APP_ID'` to the `params` argument but it didn't help. Any thoughts?

Comment: The js sdk should add the app id, so it's not the real problem.. Are you sure the user is authenticated?

Comment: Hmm no :P I'm not sure of that. I do pretty much the same thing as when I ask a user to share on his own wall. Only when I do that everything works fine. Are you saying that in order for a user to share something on _my_ page's wall that user needs to first login to my app or something like that? Why is that required for posting on my wall - but not on the user's own wall?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can, but you must be administrator of the page and you must request the access token with the correct authorization: `publish_stream, offline_access, manage_pages, read_stream`

there is a great tutorial here to get your access_token and to post message: http://sp4ce.net/computer/2012/02/15/facebook-page%3A-automatic-answer.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is official Facebook page for that:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it is not possible, and will never be:

> This functionality was never and is not intended to be available.
>
> An error message has been added for this case: "Comments may not be
>   added to a comment plugin"

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/164794086987157